# How to show the word password masked in the password field?

Tags: java, swing, passwords, password-protection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeKYJ.png)

I want to have a registration form where the label parts of the username or password will be in the text field and password field but in the password field it will be hidden. Can anyone help me? .. on Netbeans, Winform
ex: form Login facebook. I want the same username and password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the JPasswordField function
jPasswordField.getPassword();

to get the password as char[] .

Use jPasswordField1.setEchoChar('*') to mask the password characters with *.

If you wish to see the value you are inserting use

```
  jPasswordField1.setEchoChar((char)0);
```

Setting a value of 0 indicates that you wish to see the text as it is typed, similar to the behavior of a standard JTextField.

Comment: oh it's quite useful but what i need is almost the opposite. For example, you are taken to a registration form and your username and password appear right in the text box. What I want is that when I click enter, the password field will change to "*" instead of something like "123456"

Comment: ohhh i thought your trying to display what behind the stars password , you are kind of decrypting the password , that's what you trying to do, I am a bit busy now but i will get back to you as soon as I can